# Coalesce/combine 4 variables

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

I am very new with R and trying to get a combined variable out of 4 variables with identical values in a survey data set for a time series. In later years the survey combined these variables into a single one.

This is an example of a frequency table from 2004.

```
      Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.

      1    674     41.17          41.17     41.12          41.12
      2    274     16.74          57.91     16.72          57.84
      3    439     26.82          84.73     26.78          84.62
      4    250     15.27         100.00     15.25          99.88
   <NA>      2                               0.12         100.00
  Total   1639    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

The head() of the variables is this.

```
> head(data.2004$a1)
[1] 3 1 2 4 4 1
> head(data.2004$a2)
[1] 1 1 3 1 1 1
> head(data.2004$a3)
[1] 1 3 3 1 3 4
> head(data.2004$a4)
[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

These variables show how often people follow the news via newspaper (a1), radio (a2), TV (a3) and the internet (a4). The values for each variable is 1 (Daily), 2 (once or twice a week), 3 (rarely) or 4 (never). I'm trying to get a combined variable. Later years combine them into a single variable asking people how often they follow the news on either of those media.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not understand your ask. What is your expected output here?

Comment: Please post the `head()` of your dataset (or anything more relevant) and the result you would like to have. Try to think of what you would need to help someone else on your problem.

Comment: Edited the question for more clarity! Thank you! Let me know if it need further information or clarity.